# Neural Network StyleGAN Style mixing trouble

Tags: python

The neural network is loaded from GitHub with pre-trained files and successfully generates random photos. It seems to be random. But when you run the script generate_figures.py displays a photo of a mixed forest of the other two, also random. 
Question. How to make a neural network to make a mix of two user-defined rather than generated photos? 
I made changes to the code, specifying the path to your photos, but in the end, it generates all the same random not related to my photo face.

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import dnnlib
import dnnlib.tflib as tflib
import config

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Helpers for loading and using pre-trained generators.

url_ffhq        = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MEGjdvVpUsu1jB4zrXZN7Y4kBBOzizDQ' # karras2019stylegan-ffhq-1024x1024.pkl

synthesis_kwargs = dict(output_transform=dict(func=tflib.convert_images_to_uint8, nchw_to_nhwc=True), minibatch_size=4)

_Gs_cache = dict()

def load_Gs(url):
    if url not in _Gs_cache:
        with dnnlib.util.open_url(url, cache_dir=config.cache_dir) as f:
            _G, _D, Gs = pickle.load(f)
        _Gs_cache[url] = Gs
    return _Gs_cache[url]
```

## Figure 3: Style mixing.

```
def draw_style_mixing_figure(png, Gs, w, h, src_seeds, dst_seeds, style_ranges):
   print(png)

   src_latents = np.stack(np.random.RandomState(seed).randn(Gs.input_shape[1]) for seed in src_seeds)
   dst_latents = np.stack(np.random.RandomState(seed).randn(Gs.input_shape[1]) for seed in dst_seeds)
   src_dlatents = Gs.components.mapping.run(src_latents, None) # [seed, layer, component]
   dst_dlatents = Gs.components.mapping.run(dst_latents, None) # [seed, layer, component]
   src_images = Gs.components.synthesis.run(src_dlatents, randomize_noise=False, **synthesis_kwargs)
   dst_images = Gs.components.synthesis.run(dst_dlatents, randomize_noise=False, **synthesis_kwargs)

   canvas = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (w * (len(src_seeds) + 1), h * (len(dst_seeds) + 1)), 'white')

   for col, src_image in enumerate(list(src_images)):
       canvas.paste(PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\Kurmyavochka\Desktop\NN\REALISM\stylegan-master\results\1.png"), ((col + 1) * w, 0))
   for row, dst_image in enumerate(list(dst_images)):
       canvas.paste(PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\Kurmyavochka\Desktop\NN\REALISM\stylegan-master\results\2.png"), (0, (row + 1) * h))

       row_dlatents = np.stack([dst_dlatents[row]] * len(src_seeds))
       row_dlatents[:, style_ranges[row]] = src_dlatents[:, style_ranges[row]]

       row_images = Gs.components.synthesis.run(row_dlatents, randomize_noise=False, **synthesis_kwargs)

       for col, image in enumerate(list(row_images)):
           canvas.paste(PIL.Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB'), ((col + 1) * w, (row + 1) * h))
   canvas.save(png)

def main():

   tflib.init_tf()
   os.makedirs(config.result_dir, exist_ok=True)

   issa = 5067
   for iter in range(1):
       draw_style_mixing_figure(
           os.path.join(config.result_dir,
                        str(issa) + 'figure03-style-mixing.png'),
           load_Gs(url_ffhq),
           w=1024,
           h=1024,
           src_seeds=[0],
           dst_seeds=[0],
           style_ranges=[range(0, 4)] * 3 + [range(4, 8)] * 2 +
           [range(8, 18)])
       issa = issa + 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate latent representation of photos you want to fuse. Than create average vector from them. And finally, generate image with your script. Nice implementation you may find here https://github.com/Puzer/stylegan-encoder